# NSPredicate not working with array of dictionaries

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have an NSPredication with format like this:`@"Status CONTAINS[cd] shipped"`

I have an array of dictionary, here's an example:

```
{
        {
        Category = "Category 4";
        Comp = "Category 4";
        Depth = 02;
        Grade = New;
        Length = 02;
        Location = "Thousand Oaks, CA";
        Name = "3ply Mat";
        Owner = "Owner 3";
        PUP = 2;
        Status = Shipped;
        "Unit Number" = 20110507113852351;
        Width = 02;
    },
        {
        Category = "Category 4";
        Comp = "Category 4";
        Depth = 02;
        Grade = New;
        Length = 02;
        Location = "Thousand Oaks, CA";
        Name = "3ply Mat";
        Owner = "Owner 3";
        PUP = 2;
        Status = Shipped;
        "Unit Number" = 20110516094641587;
        Width = 02;
    }
)
```

But it's returning an empty array. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You want:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Status =[cd] 'shipped'"];
```

Or:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Status =[cd] %@", @"shipped"];
```

Your problem was that your predicate format had `shipped`, when it should've had `'shipped'`.  The lack of singles quotes meant it was trying to compare `[dictionary valueForKey:@"Status"]` to `[dictionary valueForKey:@"shipped"]`, instead of to the string literal `@"shipped"`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the keywords `MATCHES`, `CONTAINS` etc., against strings. As Status is not a string, I guess, you need to check it like this,

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Status = %d", Shipped];
```